# Get Context of Android Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

i have a java class that communicates with a Mysql Server trought POST method.
When i click on item in the NavigationDrawer this is what happens:

```
 chat_fragment fragment= new chat_fragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        setTitle("Chat");
```

This is my fragment.class(chat_fragment.class)

```
public class chat_fragment extends Fragment {
String username;
private ListView listView;

public chat_fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // don't know whats your rootlayout. Assuming you use a LinearLayout
    LinearLayout layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_fragment, container, false);
    listView = layout.findViewById(R.id.lv_chat); 

   return view;
}

@Overwrite
public void onActivityCreated()
{

SharedPreferences userDetails = getActivity().getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    username=userDetails.getString("Unm","");


    GetMsg getMsg=new GetMsg(listView);
    getMsg.execute("method",username);
}
```

}

I need to execute the Java Class(GetMsg) by doing the follow:

```
 GetMsg getMsg=new GetMsg(ctx);
 getMsg.execute("msg",username);
```

Usually what i do is put "this" where it says "ctx", but in the fragment that is not working..
I get the context from the Activity doing this in my Java Class:

```
ListView list;

GetMsg (ListView list){

    this.list=list;


}
```

This is my GetMsg.class onPosExecute(is AsyncTask):

```
                   String[] msg = new String[] {
                           response,

               };
               final List<String> msg_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(msg));

               ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                       (list.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, msg_list);



               list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
               list.getAdapter().notifyDatasetChanged()
```

**My problem?**
I need to add items to a ListView in the fragment, but i can't get the Fragment Context, so i not being capable of doing that, can you please help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: add getActivity() in place of ctx ..

Comment: getActivity() is getting the context of the MainActivty, not of the fragment, any suggestion, what should i post to better expose my problem?

Comment: Just pass getActivity().getApplicationContext() to GetMsg.

Comment: i am doing that in the onCreateView of the Fragment, am i doing it right?

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: Please check post , thank you!

Comment: Overwrite the onActivityCreated() method in the fragment and put the getMsg stuff in it. To make sure that getActivity() call is working. More infos here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: In my javaclass when i get the ListView to a variable i need to find it, how do i do that, because this is a fragment not a AppCompactActivity

Comment: @Ko0kiE Can you post more code. What do you want to achieve? Fill the list view with data form the getMsg stuff?

Comment: please check my post again, thank you!

Comment: you should pass only the listview to the getMsg constructor. And make the listview a member of the fragment and set it in the onCreateView() method of the Fragment.

Comment: could you please tell me how to do it? i am new at android studio development.. Thanks for your help

Comment: As this question is marked as duplicate, i can't answer anymore. So, I've edited the code of your question with the modifications to hopefully resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi, Vall0n39, i try what you gave me , but is still getting the MainActivity context, but thank you so much for your help, i will try to loof for another way. Have a nice day!

Comment: No problem! Even better is to just pass the array adapter of the listivew to the AsyncTask GetMsg. And instanciate and set the arrayadapter in the onCreateView Method of the fragment.